# WP permalink working, but why content doesn't display

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, nginx

I'm running a wp-blog on LEMP stack, I'm setting permalink fro WP Admin panel to say example.local/blog/%postname%

it shows full post name in the address bar, when I click any post, but it doesn't show any content.

here's the nginx conf file..

```
upstream example.local {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000 fail_timeout=30;
    keepalive 16;
}
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /home/ssls.com/ssl-bundle-and-crt.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /root/project1.key;
    server_name *.example.local example.local;  
    client_max_body_size 10M;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/javascript text/xml application/xml+rss;


    location ^~ /blog {
        #autoindex on;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
            alias /var/www/html/wordpress;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
            location ~ \.php$ {
                include fastcgi_params;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            }
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://example.local;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    }
    location ~ ^/static/(.*)$ {
        root /;
        try_files /root/project/project/staticfiles/$1 =404;
        expires 7d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }
location /media {
    autoindex on;
    alias /root/project/project/media; 
}
    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}
```

As you can see, URL redirect rule is set properly under /blog location. but when I click the post, it only shows blog menu bar and nothing under, I mean no post-content

down below is .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress                                                                                                                                                 %
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>                                                                                                                                          %
RewriteEngine On                                                                                                                                                  %
RewriteBase /                                                                                                                                                     %
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]                                                                                                                                    %
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f                                                                                                                               %
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d                                                                                                                               %
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]                                                                                                                                      %
```

I tried to disable .htaccess too, but still same

Comment: Do you have WP_DEBUG set to `true`, and do you see anything in your server error_log? It sounds like the page is broken but failing without showing errors.

Comment: no error log is clean, I see your point, so how to troubleshoot it? page is showing content with default plain permalink settings..

Comment: You can take a look at the [Rewrite Rules Inspector plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/) to see what is being requested - it's a bit old but still useful. Put the URL in that you are having problems with and maybe share a screenshot of the rewrite rules from that plugin. You can then compare those against the default permalink structure using the plugin.

Comment: @Alexander I've tried that plugin but still no luck

Comment: Can you share the URL and screenshot please, otherwise I'm just guessing.

Comment: URL is https://teleport.express/blog
if you click any blog post, it shows permalink working, but no content is shown.. see the screenshot below
https://ibb.co/cT80k73

Comment: I see a flash of content but it looks like that is perhaps the pre loaded state of the page. The rest looks like it loads with react so it's hard to tell where the issue is as this isn't a typical WordPress theme. Are you able to switch to TwentyNineteen and see the the post loads with a "normal" theme - then we can work out of the issue is actually permalinks or react.